# Disable css hover when touch end in touch device

Tags: javascript, html, css

**In pure JavaScript**, How can I disable the hover effect (of a div or btn ...etc) when user's touch end in touchable devices?

I have some anchors and buttons with effects on hovering, but on touch devices, the effect of touch remains visible even after the user takes his finger off the screen.

I don't want the hover effect to be completely removed from touch devices... but what I want is for the hover to end after I stop touching the element.

I tried to play with the `touchend` in JavaScript, but it don't work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

`:hover` is for pointing devices. You shouldn't be trying to optimize it for other types. Here is a definition from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover):

> The `:hover` CSS pseudo-class matches when the user interacts with an element with a pointing device, but does not necessarily activate it. It is generally triggered when the user hovers over an element with the cursor (mouse pointer).

A wise thing to do to avoid this weird behavior for non-pointing devices, is to apply the hover effect only for those who support it with [`@media (pointer: fine)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer), like so:

```css
button {
  /* Styles for all type of devices */
}

@media (pointer: fine) {
  button {
    /* Styles for pointing devices */
  }
  button:hover {
    /* Hover effects for pointing devices */
    color:red;
  }
}
```